# Play Framework 2.5 in production: "bad root server path"

Tags: docker, playframework, sbt, alpine-linux

I would like to use a prod.conf file in production inside a Docker container. I added this to my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/myapp", "-D", "config.resource=prod.conf"]
```

But I got this error:

```
Bad root server path: /opt/docker/-D
```

I get the same error when I try to run the command manually as root

```
/opt/docker/bin/myapp -D config.resource=prod.conf
```

If I run

```
/opt/docker/bin/myapp
```

It works but using the default application.conf file.

I guess there is no permission issue.

Here is my full Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8u121-alpine
WORKDIR /opt/docker
ADD opt /opt
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon:daemon", "."]
EXPOSE 9000
USER daemon
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/myapp", "-D", "config.resource=prod.conf"]
CMD []
```

**Edit:**

I got the same error locally:

```
activator clean stage
target/universal/stage/bin/myapp -D config.resource=prod.conf
Bad root server path: /home/me/Documents/MyApp-D
```

Comment: not sure about your `ADD opt /opt` should perhaps be `ADD /opt /opt`?

Comment: @user2915097 nop. the opt directory isn't in my /opt directory. this is run at staging.

Comment: before dockerizing, make sure the app runs successfully on your local machine. i.e. 


   sbt stage
   /path/to/bin -D config.reousce=prod.conf

if this won't start the app, docker will surely fail

Comment: @LiorH I forgot to say that this is related to a prod mode for Play and not related to the Docker. The detail about the Docker container is just a clue.
I do have the same error in local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no space between the `-D` and the config value. Use this instead:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/myapp", "-Dconfig.resource=prod.conf"]
```

Comment: `["bin/myapp", "-D", "config.resource=prod.conf"]` and `["bin/myapp", "-Dconfig.resource=prod.conf"]` are strictly equivalent.

Comment: @didil Have you tried it? First should result in `bin/myapp -D config.resource=prod.conf`, the second will result in `bin/myapp -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf`.

Comment: yes I already tried it but I knew it was equivalent. the space after an option is always optional.

Comment: Just to make sure: if you run inside the container `/opt/docker/bin/myapp -D config.resource=prod.conf` and `/opt/docker/bin/myapp -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf` you get the same error?

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_OPTS shall be used to avoid such errors.

`JAVA_OPTS="-Dconfig.resource=prod.conf" bin/myapp`

Worsk with command line, systemctl.

Answer (score 0):

If you use sbt plugin "DockerPlugin" you can type

`dockerEntrypoint := Seq("")`

in your build.sbt file. It will cause

```
ENTRYPOINT [""]
```

in your Dockerfile. So, then you run docker with your image you should specify in run command the following

```
bin/myapp "-Dconfig.resource=prod.conf"
```

i.e.

docker run YOUR_DOCKER_IMAGE bin/myapp "-Dconfig.resource=prod.conf"

Pay attention to quotes on -D