# Play Framework - Bad root server path for configuration file using Docker

Tags: docker, path, configuration, playframework

This post is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468559/play-framework-2-5-in-production-bad-root-server-path) but none of the solutions worked.

#### Context

I am trying to run a Scala application using the Play Framework in production using Docker.
Running the container throws a `Bad root server path: /opt/docker/-Dconfig.resource=/opt/docker/conf/production.conf` and stops.

#### Steps to build and run the docker container:

1. `build.sbt`

```
...
Docker / version := sys.env.getOrElse("BUILD_NUMBER", "0")
Docker / daemonUserUid  := None
Docker / daemonUser := "daemon"
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(9000)
dockerBaseImage := "openjdk:8-jre-alpine"
dockerUpdateLatest := true
dockerEntrypoint := Seq("/opt/docker/bin/play-scala-seed", "-Dconfig.resource=/opt/docker/conf/production.conf")
```

2. `sbt "Docker / publishLocal"`
   Produces the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
LABEL MAINTAINER="name@example.com
WORKDIR /opt/docker
COPY --chown=daemon:root opt /opt
EXPOSE 9000
USER daemon
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker/bin/play-scala-seed", "-Dconfig.resource=/opt/docker/conf/production.conf"]
CMD []
```

3. `docker run --rm -p 9000:9000 playground-api`

```
/opt/docker/bin/play-scala-seed: line 99: is_cygwin: not found
Bad root server path: /opt/docker/-Dconfig.resource=/opt/docker/conf/production.conf
```

As per [this link](https://dvirf1.github.io/play-tutorial/posts/dockerize-the-app/) one can ignore the `is_cygwin` error message.

#### What I've tried:

1. Changing the `dockerEntrypoint` from the `build.sbt` file to "-Dconfig.resource=/conf/production.conf" or "-Dconfig.resource=production.conf"
2. Putting the -Dconfig.resource to the `docker run` command:
   `docker run ... playground-api -Dconfig.resource=./conf/production.conf`

#### Setup:

sbt 1.7.2, Play Version 2.8.19, Java 1.8.0_362, Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put opt/docket in your path as play already knows it. If following example don't work try to remove `./` at the beginning.

```
dockerEntrypoint := Seq("./bin/play-scala-seed", "-Dconfig.resource=/opt/docker/conf/production.conf")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am afraid this does not work for me - it is still throwing the exact same error message when running the docker container (after rebuilding the image with the changes you proposed)